# Equivalent to POSIX mmap() in AVR-libc

Tags: c++, c, avr, core-libraries, avr-toolchain

Is there an similar function in AVR-libc/Arduino C++ to mmap()? I'm looking for a way to place machine code in memory at runtime and make it executable.

Answer (score 5):

No.

First, mmap() makes almost no sense on an AVR, as there's no memory management unit or concept of process memory to configure.  Some related concepts like sbrk() are occasionally implemented in a minimalist fashion to let library functions designed for larger computers work, but they typically only update a tracking variable or fail.  For things that are physically realizable you can write your own mmap() if you really want, either allowing (assigning) or disallowing a region, and even if you really want automatically copying part of a file off an SD card or whatever...

But more importantly, your actual goal is entirely unachievable, as the AVR is a strict Harvard Architecture which **can only execute instructions from flash**, never from RAM.

If you want to execute from RAM, try one of the various small ARM Cortex M0/M4/M3 platforms (many of which have Arduino ports), or even consider a larger Embedded Linux system, which will not necessarily be any more expensive than an Arduino.